# How do I optionally include a file in a Puppet ERB template?

Tags: ruby, puppet, erb

I'm trying to create a Puppet ERB template for a file, with some default content and an optional tail. The optional part is to be determined by the hostname/FQDN of the Ppuppet client, and need not exist. Currently, I have this:

```
<%= scope.function_file(['mod/default']) %>
<%= scope.function_file(["mod/" + @hostname, "mod/" + @fqdn, 'mod/empty']) %>
```

`mod` is the module name. I had to create an empty `mod/files/empty` so that `scope.function_file` doesn't fail if it doesn't find a file for the hostname or FQDN. I think this is ugly.

I have tried variations of:

```
<%= File.read('default') %>
<% if File.file?(@hostname) %>
<%= File.read(@hostname) %>
<$ elsif File.file?(@fqdn) %>
<%= File.read(@fqdn) %>
<& end %>
```

With files placed in the `mod/templates` directory instead of `mod/files`, but I usually got an error about missing files. Using `scope.function_template` with the files in `mod/templates` also has the same problem as `scope.function_file` - the action fails if files are missing.

How can I do this, without having to create placeholder files (like `empty` here)?

Comment: @MattSchuchard please refrain from posting nonsense. Your answer did not provide any workable methods at all. Puppet solutions are welcome, provided you actually have one. You said "this is the wrong path" without actually explaining why it's the wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `scope.function_file` in the `erb` template itself, you should consider using it in your manifest. The below should suffice and should stop you from creating the "`empty`" file.

```
$default_content = file('mod/default')
$tail = file(
  "mod/${::hostname}",
  "mod/${::fqdn}",
  "/dev/null"
)

if $tail != "" {
  $real_content = "${default_content}\n${tail}"
} else {
  $real_content = $default_content
}
```

Then in your `template` you can just use `<%= @real_content %>`

If that is the only content of the file then you can skip using a template altogether and just use the file resource as follows:

```
file { '/path/to/file':
  ensure  => file,
  content => $real_content
}
```

By using `/dev/null` you will get empty content if `mod/${::hostname}`, or `mod/${::fqdn}` do not exist. Or you can stick with your route and just add `/dev/null` to your `scope.function_file` calls.

Comment: So the final `file` declaration would have `content => file('default')+$tail`?

Comment: @muru: I updated my answer above with the case for the default content, as well as a possible solution not utilizing an erb template at all.

Comment: Thanks, though in my case the test would be `if $tail !=""`, the default content is always present. I'd probably skip the check altogether.

Comment: thats a typo. i'll correct. i meant `if $tail != ""`.